# Can a degree be revoked for minor misconduct?

Tags: university, degree, policy

I was wondering how possible it would be that, after graduating, the university would investigate a minor misconduct during college. By minor I mean, if found guilty the worst punishment would be / have been a semester suspension.

If you had already graduated, what are the possibilities that the punishment would include revoking your degree?